# document.getElementById for an element in external html

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, getelementbyid

I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Notas</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="notas.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Nombre alumno: </p>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
    <p>Nota alumno:</p>
    <input type="text" name="nota">

    <p><br></p>
    <input type="button" name="boton" value="Enviar" onclick="respuesta()">

</body>
</html>
```

And this Javascript in another file:

```
function respuesta(){

    nombrej=document.getElementById("nombre");
    document.write(nombrej);
}
```

The problem is that when I click the button the message is "null"
I have see solutions to a similar problem in the forum but I don't know what to do since there's a button. Help!

Comment: This JS is in another document? You've a pop-up or an iframe?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1qa3vu1x/ Double-check that you are including the correct JS file.

Comment: I can't see any way that could possibly give a result other then a serialisation of an HTML input element … which is what I get when I [test the code](http://jsbin.com/zicafe/1/edit?html,output). You appear to have missed the "Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem" step when you created your [MCVE].

Comment: What did you want to happen with **document.write(nombrej);**?

Comment: where is `nombrej` going to? instead of `document.write`, have you tried the `DOM`, like `document.getElementById("nombre").value = "Johnny Bravo";`

Comment: It's ***completely*** up to you, but I'm curious about why the change in accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript getElementById returns the DOM element. To get the value of that text input, you need to get the value of it.

Instead of: 
nombrej=document.getElementById("nombre");

Use:
nombrej=document.getElementById("nombre").value;

Examples: [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field)

Comment: You forgot a period before `value`

Comment: The OP said that `nombrej` was `null`. Trying to read `.value` of `null` would throw an exception.

Comment: I updated my post, thanks joh04667. @Quentin, you are correct. I read through the code and responded with what was the most obvious problem to me. T. J. Crowder's answer is more thoroughly answered.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems there:

1. You haven't declared `nombrej`. *(And shouldn't that be `nombre`?)* That means your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implict Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my blog)*. Declare your variables.
2. You've set `nombrej` to the `HTMLInputElement`. You probably wanted its value, which is on its `value` property.
3. Calling `document.write` once the page has been completed will implicitly call `document.open`, which wipes out the page and replaces it with what you write.

So `respuesta` might look something like this instead:

```
function respuesta(){

    var nombrej=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
//  ^^^--- #1                                    ^^^^^^--- #2
    console.log(nombrej);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^--- #3
}
```

---

Side note: I see you've put your `script` tag in the `head` section. You'll find a lot of people doing that and telling you to do it, but it's an anti-pattern. Unless you have a specific reason to do something else, put `script` tags at the very end of `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag. More in [YUI's guidelines](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem were the lack of declaration and that I was missing the .value in the getElementById.